# Minimizing the use of if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to minimize the conditional statements as much as possible within the following if statement, how can it be achieved?

```
if(safeHalFromCros == true){
        System.out.println("Crossbowman cannot win, Halbedier out of range");
        if(speedHalToCav < speedCavToCros){
            halberdier.setXPos(cavalier.getXPos());
            halberdier.setYPos(cavalier.getYPos());
            System.out.printf("***The winner is: %3s:\n",halberdier.toString());

        }else{
            cavalier.setXPos(crossBowMan.getXPos());
            cavalier.setYPos(crossBowMan.getYPos());
            System.out.printf("***The winner is %3s:\n",cavalier.toString());
            crossBowMan.setXPos(-1.0);
            crossBowMan.setYPos(-1.0);

        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Crossbowman has a chance to win, Halbedier is within range");
        if(speedCrosToHal < speedHalToCav && speedCrosToHal < speedCavToCros){
            System.out.println("Printing out the speeds for testing purposes");
            System.out.println("Speed of crossbowman to halberdier is: "+speedCrosToHal);
            System.out.println("Speed of halbedier to cavalier is: "+speedHalToCav);
            System.out.println("Speed of cavalier to crossbowman is: "+speedCavToCros);
            halberdier.setXPos(-1.0);
            halberdier.setYPos(-1.0);
            System.out.printf("***The winner is %3s:\n",crossBowMan.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing immediately pops out at me, except for `safeHalFromCross == true` could be reduced to `safeHalFromCross`.  I don't think you can reduce those `if`s, but it's also dependent on your code design *overall* which would be a bit too large to broach.

Comment: minimize how? 3 `if` isn't exactly excessive, especially if the clauses in the various branches don't "overlap".

Comment: Is that a homework requirement? That is nothing bad, but it helps to say that so people know you are dealing with a predefined limit rather than personal preference.

Comment: I suggest sending similar questions to the codereview sister site

Answer (score 0):

You  need to use Open-Closed Principle or Strategy Pattern

Comment: Downvoting, as the answer currently does not answer OP's question, and without further explanation on what OCP or SP bring to the table, is no better than "look up these terms and see if you learn something".

Comment: One-liner answers should, well, answer the question. Even though I am familiar with both concepts (which the OP probably is not), I do not find them immediately applicable. I would probably up-vote, or cancel my down-vote, if you edit your answer to provide some sort of sample of how to apply those principles to the problem at hand. Invoking the vast power of design pattern names, by itself, is no answer. Keep comments civil, and do not call others uneducated.

Comment: I get that you don't want to go overboard, but... Perhaps there is a blog that you think does a particularly spectacular job explaining OCP/Strategy Pattern? Providing a link to a credible source would still be helpful to those seeking an answer. Perhaps you could provide a small example of how to use OCP for the OP's question or a similar-type problem? You don't have to teach the OP everything there is to know about OCP. There is a middle-ground between "you should use an array" and "here's a super in-depth, mostly irrelevant, explanation of an array".

Comment: Strategy Pattern - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm

Comment: @coderealm: don't post those as comments, edit your answer instead. While you are at it, edit your answer to explain *why* those patterns are relevant to the OP's question. I will probably revert my vote if you do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use ? : operator in Java (if you don't want to use "if" - although the implementation is same)

Comment: +0: Not sure how this would pertain to the specific code given in the question, but it's a reasonable suggestion in general

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine as it is. But there is this technique you can use this if your code is a whole method (not just a part of the method). Again that's not really what I would do here, but it can be very useful sometimes.

```
if(!safeHalFromCros) {
    System.out.println("Crossbowman has a chance to win, Halbedier is within range");
    //...
    return;
}
if(speedHalToCav < speedCavToCros){
    //...
    System.out.printf("***The winner is: %3s:\n",halberdier.toString());
    return;
}
//...
System.out.printf("***The winner is %3s:\n",cavalier.toString());
```